# KineticJS: How to increase SVG Image quality when downscaling?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, kineticjs

I tested KineticJS 5.10 with an svg image:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 400,
    height: 400
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var img=new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: img,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
    });
    layer.add(image);
    layer.draw();

}
img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/rocket.svg";
```

After that I downscale the image (keeping the aspect ratio):

```
image.scale({
 x: 30,
y: 30
});
layer.draw();
```

After that I exported the stage as a jpeg image with quality 1.0:

```
stage.toDataURL({
            mimeType: "image/jpeg",
            quality: 1.0,
            callback: function(dataUrl) {
                // save image dataUrl to file
            }
        });
```

It turns out that the quality of the svg image is very bad only if you downscale it. When you increase the size the quality does not change.

**How can I increase teh quality when downscale an SVG image with KineticJS?**

Edit: Here is a sample I made: http://jsfiddle.net/confile/p6Eey/
The edges are very crispy and not sharp.

Comment: Can you provide more info what are you expecting? Is this demo correct http://jsbin.com/qeduto/1/edit?

Comment: Have you tried reassigning the image source after you do the scaling?

Comment: @lavrton See my edit I made an example for demonstration.

Comment: @markE What do you mean that? Here is an example I made http://jsfiddle.net/confile/p6Eey/ May be you can modify it?

Comment: I don't understand demo. Everything looks fine.

Comment: @lavrton Look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/confile/Dscr3/ Look at the black edges. They are not sharp they are crispy.

Comment: Still don't understand. In firefox and chrome I have same view for stage and for image.

Comment: @lavrton It doe not matter which browser or which image. The rendering is very poor quality. Look at the black edges they are pixelated.

Comment: @lavrton Also look here: http://jsfiddle.net/confile/p6Eey/ the same problem.

Comment: @lavrton and a much bigger problem related to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771740/kineticjs-how-can-i-export-a-stage-with-an-svg-image-on-ios

Comment: @lavrton Here you will see the difference http://jsfiddle.net/confile/2LL5M/

Comment: If you want thicker stroked outlines you can tweak the stroke-width attributes in the svg file. That it was exported differently just looks like a bug in whatever tool that saved the graphic (Adobe Illustrator?).

Comment: Yes I use Adobe Illustrator but beside the line width the downscaling quality is very bad in KineticJS.